# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'FETCH_MESSAGES' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting error, not during compilation, but in my browser,
I have attached the files here

message.js reducer file

```
import store from './index';

// ACTION TYPES
const FETCH_MESSAGES = "FETCH_MESSAGES";

// ACTIONS
export const fetchMessages = ( id ) => {
    console.log(store.getState());
    return {
        type: FETCH_MESSAGES,
        payload: id
    }
}

// REDUCERS
export default function reducer( state = -1, action ) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_MESSAGES :
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import chatReducer from './chat';
import messageReducer from './messages';
const reducer = combineReducers({
    chatStore : chatReducer,
    messageStore : messageReducer,
});
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

Error Message
[Scrrenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQnGK.png)

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox of this problem? Are these separate files of action, reducer? If so then please update your question accordingly to show the actual image inside your file directory

Comment: I'd try and avoid circular module dependencies. Right now, `index.js` depends on `messages.js` which depends on `index.js`, etc